# Les aristocrates russes francophones

Tags: comparaison-de-langues, niveau-de-langue, russe

En relisant quelques ouvrages de la littérature russe, notamment *Guerre et Paix*, où les passages en français sont très nombreux, je me suis posé des questions:

- Est-ce que l'utilisation du français au sein de l'aristocratie russe était aussi répandu, comme on le croit en lisant Tolstoï ou Pouchkine ?
- Quel pourcentage parmi eux parlaient français ? Combien de personnes ? Pendant combien de générations ?
- Ce français était-il de bonne qualité ?
- Y-avait-il des differences dialectales connues entre les français parlés en Russie et en France?

J'apprécierais toutes les informations à ce sujet (en russe, anglais ou français).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [As spoken at the Russian court](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/as-spoken-at-the-russian-court)

Comment: @jlliagre It helps, but it is still anecdotal. I am looking for somewhat stronger statistical and/or linguistic data - after all, we are probably talking about a community of thousands or possibly even hundreds of thousands people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les étapes de la francisation dans l'histoire de la Russie sont indiquées lapidairement dans l'article « Noblesse Russe » de la Wikipédia. Les lignes se rapportant à ce phénomène ont été collectées ci-dessous.

**Élisabeth Ire, un début de francisation**

Élisabeth est la fille de Pierre Ier ; elle a hérité la francophilie de son père. Continuant l'occidentalisation de la noblesse, notamment sur le modèle versaillais, la tsarine va tout d'abord retirer la plupart des prérogatives d'État de la noblesse et notamment leur obligation de service.
Les titres également tendent à s'occidentaliser, et surtout à se franciser.
La cour suit l'impératrice et le français s'impose peu à peu comme la langue des courtisans.
Les prédicats commencent également à se franciser et on voit apparaître les prédicats de majesté et altesse impériales pour la famille de l'empereur.

**Pierre III et Catherine II**

La noblesse se francise encore un peu plus et se passionne pour les intrigues de palais.
Pierre III est obligé d'abdiquer. Il meurt assassiné en juillet 1762, probablement par Grigori Orlov. Son règne n'aura duré que quelques mois.
Catherine II monte sur le trône, soutenue par la noblesse qui est alors devenue une noblesse à la française, plus honorifique qu'autre chose.

**Alexandre Ier et Nicolas Ier**

Élevé à la française [Alexandre Ier], il continua la francisation de la noblesse. Ainsi, le titre de comte, qui jusque-là était dérivé de l'allemand graf (граф), prit son équivalent français. Le titre de prince fut définitivement substitué à celui de kniaz.
Nicolas Ier, élevé durant les troubles de la Révolution française et les guerres napoléoniennes, conserve une certaine haine pour le libéralisme.

**Alexandre II et Alexandre III**

Une politique de russification est lancée [sous Alexandre III] et la francisation de la cour est progressivement abandonnée, au profit des anciens titres russes, ou d'équivalents spécialement créés.

---

Voici une récapitulation des raisons expliquant pourquoi la noblesse russe parlait français, l'une de celles-ci étant assez invraisemblable. On trouve les détails dans l'article [« Pourquoi la noblesse russe parlait-elle français ? »](https://fr.rbth.com/%C3%A9ducation/84831-empire-russe-langue-francais) .

- Rester incompris des domestiques
- Langue internationale dans la politique européenne
- Un afflux de tuteurs français
- S’élever au-dessus du lot

C'est un article qui donne certains détails comme par exemple la possibilité qu'un prince russe, tel que Dimitri Golitsyne (gouverneur de Moscou) puisse parler russe avec un fort accent (français, faudra-t-il croire) et fasse d'innombrables fautes d'orthographe en russe, ou comme celle de l'échec d'un détenu français, qui se faisant passer pour un prince de la dynastie des Bourbons et de ce fait ayant pu en arriver à être sur le point d'épouser une fille de la noblesse avait été démasqué par des russes plus instruits que lui.

On doit conclure d'après les constatations suivantes que l'on peut lire dans cet article que le niveau du français parlé par la noblesse russe du XIXe siècle était très élevé.

> *Les nobles russes du XIXe siècle ont très rapidement parlé français couramment. Le prince Dimitri Golitsyne, comme beaucoup d'autres, était ainsi plus à l'aise quand il parlait français que quand il avait recours au russe.*

> *Le français était largement utilisé dans les lettres d'amour et les correspondances privées, même après que Nicolas Ier a décidé que tous les documents d'État devraient être rédigés uniquement en russe. La philologue russe Varvara Blinokhvatova remarque que le fait qu'une œuvre littéraire ou artistique appartienne à la culture française suffisait à « justifier » son existence aux yeux des nobles russes. On peut certainement considérer la noblesse russe du XIXe siècle comme bilingue ; et cette connaissance du français leur permettait de se reconnaître mutuellement, et de repérer les imposteurs parmi eux.*

> *Les Français eux-mêmes ont d’ailleurs reconnu les compétences des Russes dans la maîtrise de leur langue et de leur culture. Dans Le Rouge et le Noir (1830) de Stendhal, le héros, Julien Sorel, admire le prince Korasoff, un noble russe qui enseigne à un jeune Français les manières les plus raffinées de la société. Avec Korasoff, Julien « connut enfin la haute fatuité. Il s’était lié avec de jeunes seigneurs russes qui l’initièrent », écrivait l’auteur, démontrant que les Russes étaient réellement ceux qui portaient et préservaient la haute culture.*

L'article suivant développe  le thème de l'article précédent concernant le choix du français plutôt que d'une autre langue : « [Pourquoi parlait-on français en Russie?](https://fr.rbth.com/art/culture/2017/05/26/pourquoi-parlait-on-francais-en-russie_770977) ».

*Autre article fournissant des détails supplémentaires*

https://www.saintjeanlethomas.net/L-influence-francaise-dans-la-Russie-des-tsars_a158.html

Comment: Merci pour la reponse. J'avoue que ça ne me convainc pas a 100%: ça manque de chiffres et l'histoire des titres ne suffit pas pour un comparaison linquistique. Alors que l'étude des langues est certainement une partie d'education aristocratique, je ne vois pourquoi les russes prefereraient le français pour être bilangue. Par exemple, l'Allemangne  et l'Autriche étaient plus proches à la Russie politiquement, Pierre le Grande adorait les hollandais et les allemands, alors que ses descendants tous avaient la géneologie allemande et souvent parlaient l'allemand comme leur langue maternelle.

Comment: @Vadim Bien sûr, je ne pense pas non plus que cet article soit le dernier mot sur ce fait historique. Je l'ai mentionné parce qu'il apportait quand même quelque chose dans le contexte de votre étude. Il faut néanmoins tenir compte dans cette question de pourquoi le français et pas l'allemand que depuis le traité de Westphalie (1648) a été «  établi[e] la nouvelle réalité européenne des États souverains ; une réalité où le français était la nouvelle langue diplomatique », ainsi que le mentionne cet article.